# Oracle sql - query based on other column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

```
CUST_ITEM
ITEM   LINE_NO   LINK_LINE_NO
100      1          null
200      2          1
300      3          null
```

I want to bring the result as:

```
ITEM   LINE_NO   TYPE          REF_ITEM    REF_LINE_NO 
100      1       Main             200         200
200      2       Linked           100         100
300      3       Independent      null        null
```

Item: 100 is the Main item because item: 200 is attached to it
Item: 200 is a Linked item because it is attached to Item: 100
Item: 300 is independent, it is not Main or Linked

What's the way to do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do the references mean on the "main" row?  What if there are multiple links?  And why is the `ref_line_no` the same as the `ref_item`?

Comment: If there are multiple dependent records (of levels > 2), what should be in `ref_item` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sample data you posted, one option might be this (read comments within code).

```
SQL> WITH
  2     cust_item (item, line_no, link_line_no)
  3     AS
  4  -- sample data
  5        (SELECT 100, 1, NULL FROM DUAL
  6         UNION ALL
  7         SELECT 200, 2, 1 FROM DUAL
  8         UNION ALL
  9         SELECT 300, 3, NULL FROM DUAL),
 10     temp
 11     AS
 12  -- find main and linked items
 13        (SELECT a.item,
 14                a.line_no,
 15                (SELECT MIN (b.item)
 16                   FROM cust_item b
 17                  WHERE b.link_line_no = a.line_no) linked_item,
 18                (SELECT MIN (c.item)
 19                   FROM cust_item c
 20                  WHERE c.line_no = a.link_line_no) main_Item
 21           FROM cust_item a)
 22  -- final result
 23    SELECT t.item,
 24           t.line_no,
 25           CASE
 26              WHEN t.linked_item IS NOT NULL THEN 'Main'
 27              WHEN t.main_item IS NOT NULL THEN 'Linked'
 28              ELSE 'Independent'
 29           END TYPE,
 30           COALESCE (t.linked_item, t.main_item) ref_item
 31      FROM temp t
 32  ORDER BY t.line_no
 33  /
```

---

```
      ITEM    LINE_NO TYPE          REF_ITEM
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
       100          1 Main               200
       200          2 Linked             100
       300          3 Independent

SQL>
```

However, what would be result if there were more items "linked" to each other?

Answer (score 1):

```
select tab1.item, tab1.line_no, nvl(rel.type, 'Independent'), rel.to_item from tab1
left join
(
  select t1.item, 'Main' as Type, t2.item to_item from tab1 t1, tab1 t2 where t1.LINE_NO = t2.LINK_LINE_NO
  union
  select t2.item, 'Linked' Type, t1.item from_item from tab1 t1, tab1 t2 where t1.LINE_NO = t2.LINK_LINE_NO
) rel
on tab1.item = rel.item
```

You can check it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e56644c50aa1e7d1aa2a1536e351c41f)

Answer (score 0):

The following does not put in the references for "main", because it is unclear what happens if there are multiple matches.

For the rest, you can use:

```
select ci.*,
       (case when ci.link_line_no is not null then 'linked'
             when cil.line_no is not not null then 'main'
             else 'independent'
        end) as type,
       cil.item as ref_item,
       cil.item as ref_line_no
from cust_item ci left join
     cust_item cil
     on ci.link_line_no = cil.line_no;
```